# Optimize calculation of a large set of binary predicate based rules

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, decision-tree, predicate, boolean-logic

I have a known and limited set of binary predicates: `A, B, C, ...`

And a large set of rules, containing the predicates with `OR, AND, NOT` operators. i.e

```
R1 = A AND B
R2 = NOT(C) OR B
R3 = ((A OR B) AND C) OR NOT(C)
```

When getting a binary assignment for all the predicates, I want to optimize the calculation of the rules.

For that, I can modify the rule definition however I wish, as long as the logic won't change (same predicate assignment will give same calculated result on each rule).

I was thinking of creating some sort of a joint decision tree, but couldn't see how I can tell what is the optimized arrangement.

Note: I don't care about the complexity of building the calculating algorithm, only the calculation complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a small number of predicates you can calculate all results in advance to create a cache. Note that you will have 2 ^ (the number of predicates) entries in your cache.

For a large number of predicates you can't do this. I'd say this sounds like dynamic programming, as the rules may have overlapping components. To increase this overlap you could rewrite all rules to use a single type of operation, e.g. NAND. From this you can then create a graph where the predicates are the input and the rules are the output.

So your rules would look like:

```
R1 = (A NAND B) NAND (A NAND B)
R2 = (B NAND B) NAND C
R3 = (A NAND A) NAND (B NAND B) NAND C
```

You can already see some overlap. This will increase with the number of rules. Your graph would look like this:

[image: computation graph]

Once you get the binary assignment, you can compute the graph from left to right. Or in dynamic programming style, you start with R1 and cache all intermediate results for later use, then do the same for R2 and R3.